# Angular2 Update FormGroup nested value?

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, components

I have this inside a component:

```
private formBuilder: FormBuilder

...

signupForm: FormGroup;

...

this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name':             [null, Validators.required],
  'account':          this.formBuilder.group({
    'email':          [null, [Validators.required, ...]],
    'confirm_email':  [null, Validators.required],
  }, {validator: ValidationService.emailMatcher}),
  'password':         [null, [Validators.required,...]]
});
```

And I want to set the value for the email field. I tried this, but no luck:

```
this.signupForm.patchValue({'email': 'myvalue@asd.com'});
```

But the value is nested, so whats the sintax in this case? I also tried:

```
this.signupForm.patchValue({'account.email': 'myvalue@asd.com'});
```

Also searched here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#patchValue-anchor

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

`this.signupForm.patchValue({account:{email: 'myvalue@asd.com'}});`

Another solution is:

```
(<FormGroup>this.signupForm.controls['account']).controls['email'].patchValue('myvalue@asd.com');
```

Sorry for bad indentation.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! I do not know why I didn't realize with the solution ... now it seems obvious!

Comment: How to use variable in place of account in your above solution.

Comment: you could use this syntax
this.signupForm.patchValue({[variable]:{email: 'myvalue@asd.com'}});

Comment: Thank you so much.